# Reset object property getter/setter after using "defineProperty" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, properties, prototype

I want to "reset" the getter/setter after I changed them using "defineProperty".

The output of the example should be 1 -> nope -> 1, but I just get "undefined".

How can I clear the custom getter, so I it will go with the native default getter?

```js
var obj = {
 a: '1',
  b: '2'
};

console.log(obj.a);

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'a', {
  get: function(){ return 'nope'; },
  configurable: true
});

console.log(obj.a);

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'a', {
  get: undefined,
  configurable: true
});

console.log(obj.a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you'd ever get back to your defaults without cloning obj - because that first getter in essence destroys the original value of 'a'; it's the same as saying `obj.a = 'nope'`.

Something like this will work:

```
let obj = {
    a: '1',
  b: '2'
};
const objOrig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

console.log(obj.a);

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'a', {
  get: function(){ return 'nope'; },
  configurable: true
});

console.log(obj.a);

obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objOrig))

console.log(obj.a);
```

And note if you ever need to delete a getter you can;

```
delete obj.a
```

but it won't revert to the original declaration; 'a' is lost at this point.

Comment: Thanks, nice idea! In my case the "obj" is to complex to clone it the JSON way. But for me it is enough to just clone or store the obj.a value (`var a_clone = obj.a`) and use `delete obj.a` and reassign it with `obj.a = a_clone`. This way I got it work. Thanks!